# Android: Master detail project has errors right after creation

Tags: java, android

I have the android 4.1 and 4.0 SDK installed on my laptop. I've done plenty of projects just using a blank activity, but when I decided to try a "master detail flow" example from within Eclipse (create new Android project, select MasterDetailFlow) the other day it wouldn't even let me build. I have errors right off the bat. Surely this can't be right? Here are the errors:

(1)The method onItemSelected(String) of type ItemListActivity must override a superclass method ItemListActivity.java   /Master Detail/src/com/example/master/detail    line 39 Java Problem

(2)The method onItemSelected(String) of type new ItemListFragment.Callbacks(){} must override a superclass method   ItemListFragment.java   /Master Detail/src/com/example/master/detail    line 27 Java Problem

I'd like to try and use the master detail forms so I can understand more advanced android layouts. Could anyone point me into a better direction with that as well? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ugh, that's a pain, but it's a pretty simple solution.  The rules for when you should/shouldn't use @Override switched from Java 5 to Java 6, so depending on Eclipse's default JDK it'll sometimes yell at you when @Override isn't there but should be, or vice versa.

Set the compiler level in Eclipse to at least JDK 6 and the errors will magically disappear :)

Comment: Where do I find this in the settings?

Comment: Window > Preferences > Java > Compiler  .  Set to at least 1.6 :)

Comment: Hmm. Right click on your project and go to Properties > Java Build to verify you don't have project-specific settings overriding the default of 1.7.  If that doesn't work, add @Override above each method listed as needing to override a superclass.